# Unable to upload File through HTTP request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Here are Settings in HTTP POST request. I have tried changing the Client Implementation to all possible options - Java, blank, HTTPClient4. But, no luck

```
POST
http://192.168.7.101/R3.Web/File/SaveFileentityID=Contact&entityIId=0&companyId=PRGDATA

POST data:
--79pPqMQy27etoiZ9KD_ZvALl72vJyd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="excelupload"; filename="R3 Product Backlog_V2.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

<actual file content, not shown here>
--79pPqMQy27etoiZ9KD_ZvALl72vJyd--


[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://192.168.7.101
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Accept: */*
Referer: http://192.168.7.101/R3.Web/Account/AccountAccessWizard
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 23562
Host: 192.168.7.101
```

I am getting the following response

> isSuccess:false

If I pass the same request on browser, it works. Please let me know if
I need to change settings.

HTTP header Manager details:

```
Origin  http://${host}
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Content-Type    multipart/form-data
Accept  */*
Referer http://${host}/R3.Web/Account/AccountAccessWizard
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8
Host    ${host}
Connection  keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a file upload test scenario is just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Copy the file you will be uploading into JMeter's "bin" folder
2. Start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
3. Perform file upload in the browser
4. Stop HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
5. Use generated [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler in your script.

See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more detailed instructions if required.

---

If the upload still doesn't work first thing to do is checking *jmeter.log* file and application under test logs.

If there is nothing suspicious there - use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture requests sent by JMeter and by the real browser and compare them. Detect and eliminate the differences by amending JMeter's configuration to be 100% match with what browser does.